# Macro to Start at a Specific Row / Cell and Continuously Paste to the Next Empty Row / Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a Macro that will copy every other value in a column of data and paste continuously to a new column in a new sheet. In my code below, the `For i = 4 To LastRowC Step 2` loop is working, as it works out that the first empty row to paste is in the right spot.

However, for the `For i = 4 To LastRowC Step 2` loop, the macro is finding a row too far down, as there is another filled row throwing it off, and I need to designate it to start pasting higher up at a specific cell. But it still needs to look for empty rows for pasting after for the duration of the for loop. Is this possible?

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyRange()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim LastRowC As Long

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\NGiuliano\Desktop\UPLOADS2\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
            LastRowC = wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 4 To LastRowC Step 2
                wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Copy
                wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Next i

            For j = 4 To LastRowC Step 2
                wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Copy
                wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Next j

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will build on the code I provided in the last question:

```
Dim nextrow as Long 'Option 1; this dimension isn't appropriate for Option 2
nextrow = 2 'starting row for pasting, used for Option 1

For i = 4 to LastRowC Step 2
    'Use Cells(i,"B") or Range("B" & i)

    'Option 1, use a counter (declare "nextrow" as Long and define before the loop, e.g., 2)
    wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Cells(nextrow,16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    nextrow = nextrow + 1

    'Option 2, find next cell each time using "end(xldown)" 
    set nextcell = wkbDest.Worksheets("WIP").Cells(2,16).End(xlDown).Offset(1)
    nextcell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Next i
```

You can use either option, where `nextrow` is the row number and `nextcell` is the actual next cell that would be used.

---

In your code you're attempting to use a standard `lastrow` syntax (`.End(xlUp)`), which is great if needed... are you familiar with *how* that script actually works?

```
With Workbooks("Name").Sheets("Name")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Option 1
    set nextcell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'Option 2
End With
```

In order it goes:

- Find the workbook
- Find the worksheet
- Find the cell

  - Column found
  - Count of ALL rows in column found (i.e., 1,048,576)
- From the last counted row go xlUp to the next cell with data

Now, you can either `set` that as a range, or you can `.row`/`.column` to find the parameter you want.  In your example you did neither, and actually have inappropriate syntax in your `.pastespecial` line.

Spend some time to read up on the functionality of each line in your code and that might help move you forward!

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Yes, I have used End xlUp and I have never used End xlDown.  I tried End xlDown a couple times too, but it seems I was not using the correct logic. Thanks again.